# Сложение матриц с помощью функции sum и zip

Tags: python-3.x, матрицы

Подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибся, не могу въехать.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]

b = [[9, 8, 7],
    [6, 5, 4],
    [3, 2, 1]]

x = [map(sum, zip(*i)) for i in zip(a, b)]

print(x)
```

Должно быть `[[10,10,10],[10,10,10],[10,10,10]]`

А получается `[<map object at 0x0232FE08>, <map object at 0x0232FE38>, <map object at 0x0232FF28>]`

Меня интересует именно этот подход, так как с использованием вложенного цикла for:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]

b = [[9, 8, 7],
    [6, 5, 4],
    [3, 2, 1]]

x = [[0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0]]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        x[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j]
  
[print(i) for i in x]
```

и использованием метода понимания вложенного списка я уже разобрался:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]

b = [[9, 8, 7],
    [6, 5, 4],
    [3, 2, 1]]

x = [[a[i][j] + b[i][j] for j in range(len(a[0]))] for i in range(len(a))]

[print(i) for i in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Преобразуйте объект `map` в `list`:

```
x = [list(map(sum, zip(*i))) for i in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Блин, я так пробывал и у меня не получалось( наверное из-за невнимательности где-то скобу пропустил и мучался  не знаю сколько. Во всяком случае СПАСИБО!

Comment: @bgl1215, если вам помог этот ответ, примите его (серая галочка слева).